# Are there any differences between "exclusive bus lane" and "bus only"?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-meaning, legalese

1. "exclusive bus lane" and "bus only" means the same?
2. what's the differences about using "exclusive" and "only"?
   For example: "handicapped parking only" but in Taiwan, we use "handicapped exclusive parking space".  Is it correct?

Comment: They mean the same, but "Bus Only" is shorter, simpler and can be written larger on the same size sign and is therefore preferable. Likewise "Emergency Use Only" (sometimes accompanied by "Alarm Will Sound") is typically what is printed on doors intended to be used only during emergencies.

Comment: Part 3 is an unrelated to parts 1 and 2. Please ask separate questions, and do not ask more questions as an answer. I'm going to edit out part 3.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding 1) and 2), the meanings of each pair are the same. Actual wording probably depends on local dialect, regulations or space availability for the sign.

Comment: But to remain unlocked it must first *be* unlocked. Really the sign is likely trying to say "This door should only be *unlocked* in the case of an emergency". Also, the way you have #3 phrased it implies that the lock is there so that one can *lock* the door in cases of emergency.